# create a custom left navigation for default.aspx in sahrepoint O365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am presently working in Sharepoint O365. I need to build a custom left navigation for only my default.aspx page using Sharepoint designer, while keeping the normal navigation for the rest of the site. I have seen it is possible in Sharepoint 2010. However, I am unaware of any workaround in O365. Any knowledge regarding this shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the codeless solution:

[Custom Left Navigation in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-left-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Or use custom html code to make a navigation：
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp